# Using Thread Moving Files from PC to Remote Device

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, windows-ce, rapi

Using `RAPI2` to send file from PC to a Remote Device.

When using the line without `Threads`, it works fine:

```
RemoteFile.CopyFileToDevice(PdtRemoteDevice, "C:\sample.txt", "\test\sample.txt", True)
```

But when I try to put that line above inside a `Thread`, it returns an error that the device is not connected.

How do I use `RAPI2`'s `CopyFileToDevice` using Thread?

Not using `Thread` will make the application looks like it hanged. So, I don't think a user would appreciate an application that would says not responding.

My Code:

```
Imports System.Devices
Imports System.Devices.RemoteDeviceManager

Public Class FormHome
   Dim PdtRemoteDevice As RemoteDevice
   Dim Devicemanager As New RemoteDeviceManager

   Private Sub ButtonHomeCopyToDevice_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonHomeCopyToDevice.Click
      PdtRemoteDevice = Devicemanager.Devices.FirstConnectedDevice

      If PdtRemoteDevice Is Nothing Then
         MessageBox.Show("No Device Connected, Please Try Again")
         Exit Sub
      Else
         Dim Th As Thread
         Th = New Thread(AddressOf UploadDatabase)
         Th.IsBackground = True
         Th.Start()
      End If
   End Sub

   Private Sub UploadDatabase()
      Using PdtRemoteDevice = Devicemanager.Devices.FirstConnectedDevice
         If Not (PdtRemoteDevice Is Nothing) Then
            RemoteFile.CopyFileToDevice(PdtRemoteDevice, "C:\sample.txt", "\test\sample.txt", True)
         End If
      End Using
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to post the rest of the code related to this issue. We should have a minimal, yet complete, set of code to work from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it works:

```
Private Sub UploadDatabase()
    Using rdm As New RemoteDeviceManager
        Using d As RemoteDevice = rdm.Devices.FirstConnectedDevice
            If Not (d Is Nothing) Then
                RemoteFile.CopyFileToDevice( _
                    d, "C:\sample.txt", "\test\sample.txt", True)
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Error Returned at `rdm As New RemoteDeviceManager`. It says, `InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code`. It also says `Specified cast is not valid.`

Comment: @jaa2013 - I can't test the code, but you should try to debug this yourself. The thing I'm going for is to instantiate all of the objects in the new thread and not to introduce any cross-thread issues.

Answer (score 0):

Create a form, add the RAPI2 library as a reference, then add two buttons and this code:

```
Imports System.Devices
Imports System.Devices.RemoteDeviceManager
Imports System.Devices.RemoteDevice
Imports System.Devices.RemoteFile


Public Class Form1
    Dim dev As RemoteDevice
    Dim mgr As New System.Devices.RemoteDeviceManager


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        dev = mgr.Devices.FirstConnectedDevice

        If dev Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("No device connected")
        Else
            MsgBox("Connected to: " & dev.Name)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim RAPIfile As RemoteFile

        dev = mgr.Devices.FirstConnectedDevice
        Try
            RAPIfile.CopyFileToDevice(dev, "C:\temp\test1.txt", "\Application\Inventory\test1.txt", True)
        Catch
            MsgBox("error")
        End Try

        RAPIfile = Nothing

    End Sub

End Class
```